# How use QPageSetupDialog on Mac if this system doesn't have any printers?

Tags: macos, qt

I use Qt 5.15.2 on Mac 10.14.6

I try open QPageSetupDialog

```
QPrinter printer
QPageSetupDialog page(&printer);
page.exec();
```

but this dialog doesn't open and shows message "QPageSetupDialog: Cannot be used on non-native printers"

I examined the source code and found that QPageSetupDialog opens if QPrinter has output format NativeFormat, but I don't can set this format because QPrinter ignores it if system doesn't have printers.

How can I solve this problem?

Answer (score 0):

I've got the same problem here. The problem is, that starting from Qt5.6 the standard output format of the printers changed from NativeFormat to PdfFormat. There are several related QTBugs (e.g. QTBUG-44940, QTBUG-57597) but no working fix, at least for me.

In the very end I've created my own (simple) page setup dialog.

head file: simplepagesetupdialog.h

```
#ifndef SIMPLEPAGESETUPDIALOG_H
#define SIMPLEPAGESETUPDIALOG_H

#include <QDialog>
#include <QPrinter>
#include <QComboBox>
#include <QLineEdit>
#include <QRadioButton>

//-------------------------------------------------------------------------
class SimplePageSetupDialog : public QDialog
{
    Q_OBJECT

public:
    explicit SimplePageSetupDialog(QPrinter *pPrinter, QWidget *parent = 0);
    ~SimplePageSetupDialog();

private slots:
    void slot_pagesetup_accepted(void);

private:
    void createSimplePageSetupDialog(void);

    QPrinter *mpSetupPrinter;

    struct tSimplePageSetupDialog {
        QComboBox *paperSize;
        QRadioButton *orientationP;
        QRadioButton *orientationL;
        QLineEdit *marginLeft;
        QLineEdit *marginRight;
        QLineEdit *marginTop;
        QLineEdit *marginBottom;
    }GuiSimplePageSetupDialog;

    struct tSimplePageSetupDialog *uiPageSetup;
};

#endif // SIMPLEPAGESETUPDIALOG_H
```

Source file: simplepagesetupdialog.cpp

```
#include "simplepagesetupdialog.h"

#include <QGridLayout>
#include <QLabel>
#include <QGroupBox>
#include <QPushButton>
#include <QSpacerItem>
#include <QPrinterInfo>
#include <QPageSize>

#include <QDebug>


// This class is a workarround for QTBUG-44940, QTBUG-57597
// The problem is, that the QPageSetupDialog is not showing up on Mac OS 10.14

// Avoid redefinition of same connection between same elements
#define connect(src, sig, trgt, slt) connect(src, sig, trgt, slt, Qt::UniqueConnection)

///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
// SimplePageSetupDialog class
///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

/*-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------*
 * Dialog constructor
 *-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------*/
SimplePageSetupDialog::SimplePageSetupDialog(QPrinter *pPrinter, QWidget *parent) :
    QDialog(parent),
    mpSetupPrinter(pPrinter)
{
    createSimplePageSetupDialog();
}

/*-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------*
 * Dialog destructor
 *-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------*/
SimplePageSetupDialog::~SimplePageSetupDialog()
{
    //
}

/*-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------*
 * Create page setup dialog elements
 *-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------*/
void SimplePageSetupDialog::createSimplePageSetupDialog()
{
    bool bManualList = false;
    uiPageSetup = &GuiSimplePageSetupDialog;

    // Paper size ======================================================================
    // Create groupbox for paper size
    QHBoxLayout *pHBoxLayoutPaper = new QHBoxLayout();
    uiPageSetup->paperSize = new QComboBox();

    QPrinterInfo *pPrinterInfo = new QPrinterInfo(QPrinterInfo::defaultPrinter());
    QList<QPageSize> supportedPageSizes = pPrinterInfo->supportedPageSizes();
    if (supportedPageSizes.isEmpty()){
        //  Create manual pagesize list
        bManualList = true;
        for(int id = (int)QPageSize::A4; id < (int)QPageSize::LastPageSize; id++){
            QPageSize pz((QPageSize::PageSizeId)id);
            if (pz.isValid())
                supportedPageSizes.append(pz);
        }
    }

    int curPageSizeId = mpSetupPrinter->pageLayout().pageSize().id();
    int iIdxCnt = 0, iCurIdx = 0;
    foreach(QPageSize pz, supportedPageSizes)
    {
        if (bManualList == false)
            uiPageSetup->paperSize->addItem(pz.name());
        else
            uiPageSetup->paperSize->addItem(pz.name() + QString(" (%1 x %2 mm)")
                .arg(QString::number(pz.size(QPageSize::Millimeter).width()))
                .arg(QString::number(pz.size(QPageSize::Millimeter).height())));

        if (pz.id() == curPageSizeId)
            iCurIdx = iIdxCnt;
        iIdxCnt++;
    }
    uiPageSetup->paperSize->setCurrentIndex(iCurIdx);
    QLabel *pLabelPaperSize = new QLabel("Size:");
    pHBoxLayoutPaper->addWidget(pLabelPaperSize);
    pHBoxLayoutPaper->addWidget(uiPageSetup->paperSize);
    QGroupBox *pGroupboxPaper = new QGroupBox();
    pGroupboxPaper->setTitle("Paper");
    pGroupboxPaper->setLayout(pHBoxLayoutPaper);

    // Create groupbox for orientation
    QGridLayout* pGridLayoutOrientation = new QGridLayout();
    uiPageSetup->orientationP = new QRadioButton("Portrait");
    uiPageSetup->orientationP->setChecked(mpSetupPrinter->pageLayout().orientation() == QPageLayout::Portrait);
    uiPageSetup->orientationL = new QRadioButton("Landscape");
    uiPageSetup->orientationL->setChecked(mpSetupPrinter->pageLayout().orientation() == QPageLayout::Landscape);
    pGridLayoutOrientation->addWidget(uiPageSetup->orientationP,1,1);
    pGridLayoutOrientation->addWidget(uiPageSetup->orientationL,2,1);
    QGroupBox *pGroupboxOrientation = new QGroupBox();
    pGroupboxOrientation->setTitle("Orientation");
    pGroupboxOrientation->setLayout(pGridLayoutOrientation);

    // Create groupbox for Margins
    qreal left, top, right, bottom;
    int iUnit = mpSetupPrinter->pageLayout().units();
    mpSetupPrinter->getPageMargins(&left, &top, &right, &bottom, QPrinter::Millimeter);

    qDebug() << "unit " << iUnit;
    uint8_t iPrecision = 3;
    QGridLayout* pGridLayoutMargins = new QGridLayout();
    uiPageSetup->marginTop = new QLineEdit();
    uiPageSetup->marginTop->setFixedWidth(70);
    uiPageSetup->marginTop->setText(QString::number((mpSetupPrinter->pageLayout().margins().top()), 'f', iPrecision));
    uiPageSetup->marginLeft = new QLineEdit();
    uiPageSetup->marginLeft->setFixedWidth(70);
    uiPageSetup->marginLeft->setText(QString::number((mpSetupPrinter->pageLayout().margins().left()), 'f', iPrecision));
    uiPageSetup->marginRight = new QLineEdit();
    uiPageSetup->marginRight->setFixedWidth(70);
    uiPageSetup->marginRight->setText(QString::number((mpSetupPrinter->pageLayout().margins().right()), 'f', iPrecision));
    uiPageSetup->marginBottom = new QLineEdit();
    uiPageSetup->marginBottom->setFixedWidth(70);
    uiPageSetup->marginBottom->setText(QString::number((mpSetupPrinter->pageLayout().margins().bottom()), 'f', iPrecision));
    QLabel* pLabelMarginTop = new QLabel("Top:");
    QLabel* pLabelMarginLeft = new QLabel("Left:");
    QLabel* pLabelMarginRight = new QLabel("Right:");
    QLabel* pLabelMarginBottom = new QLabel("Bottom:");
    pGridLayoutMargins->addWidget(pLabelMarginLeft,1,1);
    pGridLayoutMargins->addWidget(uiPageSetup->marginLeft,1,2);
    pGridLayoutMargins->addWidget(pLabelMarginRight,1,3);
    pGridLayoutMargins->addWidget(uiPageSetup->marginRight,1,4);
    pGridLayoutMargins->addWidget(pLabelMarginTop,2,1);
    pGridLayoutMargins->addWidget(uiPageSetup->marginTop,2,2);
    pGridLayoutMargins->addWidget(pLabelMarginBottom,2,3);
    pGridLayoutMargins->addWidget(uiPageSetup->marginBottom,2,4);
    QGroupBox *pGroupboxMargins = new QGroupBox();
    pGroupboxMargins->setTitle(QString("Marings (mm)"));
    pGroupboxMargins->setLayout(pGridLayoutMargins);

    // Create pushbuttons
    QPushButton *pPushButtonOK = new QPushButton(QString("OK"));
    connect(pPushButtonOK, SIGNAL(clicked()), this, SLOT(slot_pagesetup_accepted()));
    connect(pPushButtonOK, SIGNAL(clicked()), this, SLOT(accept()));
    connect(pPushButtonOK, SIGNAL(clicked()), this, SLOT(deleteLater()));

    QPushButton *pPushButtonCancel = new QPushButton(QString("Cancel"));
    connect(pPushButtonCancel, SIGNAL(clicked()), this, SLOT(reject()));
    connect(pPushButtonCancel, SIGNAL(clicked()), this, SLOT(deleteLater()));

    QSpacerItem* spacer = new QSpacerItem( 20, 20, QSizePolicy::Expanding, QSizePolicy::Minimum);

    QHBoxLayout *pHBoxLayoutButtons = new QHBoxLayout();
    pHBoxLayoutButtons->addItem(spacer);
    pHBoxLayoutButtons->addWidget(pPushButtonOK);
    pHBoxLayoutButtons->addWidget(pPushButtonCancel);
    pHBoxLayoutButtons->setAlignment(Qt::AlignRight);
    pHBoxLayoutButtons->setSizeConstraint(pHBoxLayoutButtons->SetFixedSize);

    QGridLayout *pGridlayoutPageSetupDialog = new QGridLayout;
    pGridlayoutPageSetupDialog->addWidget(pGroupboxPaper, 1, 1, 1, 2);
    pGridlayoutPageSetupDialog->addWidget(pGroupboxOrientation, 2, 1);
    pGridlayoutPageSetupDialog->addWidget(pGroupboxMargins, 2, 2);


    // Create overlaying layout
    QVBoxLayout *pVBoxLayoutButtons = new QVBoxLayout();
    pVBoxLayoutButtons->addLayout(pGridlayoutPageSetupDialog);
    pVBoxLayoutButtons->addLayout(pHBoxLayoutButtons);
    pVBoxLayoutButtons->setSizeConstraint(pVBoxLayoutButtons->SetFixedSize);

    this->setLayout(pVBoxLayoutButtons);
    this->setWindowTitle(QString("Page Setup"));
}


/*-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------*
 * Page setup accepted
 *-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------*/
void SimplePageSetupDialog::slot_pagesetup_accepted()
{
    if (mpSetupPrinter != 0)
    {
        // Get paper size
        QPrinterInfo *pPrinterInfo = new QPrinterInfo(QPrinterInfo::defaultPrinter());
        QList<QPageSize> supportedPageSizes = pPrinterInfo->supportedPageSizes();

        if (supportedPageSizes.isEmpty()){
            for(int id = QPageSize::A4; id < QPageSize::LastPageSize; id++){
                QPageSize pz((QPageSize::PageSizeId)id);
                if (pz.isValid())
                    supportedPageSizes.append(pz);
            }
        }

        int curPageSizeId = uiPageSetup->paperSize->currentIndex();
        if ((curPageSizeId > -1) && (curPageSizeId < supportedPageSizes.length()))
        {
            mpSetupPrinter->setPageSize(supportedPageSizes.at(curPageSizeId));
        }

        // Get Orientation
        if (uiPageSetup->orientationP->isChecked())
            mpSetupPrinter->setOrientation(QPrinter::Portrait);
        else
            mpSetupPrinter->setOrientation(QPrinter::Landscape);

        // Get Margins
        qreal left, top, right, bottom;
        qreal newLeft, newTop, newRight, newBottom;
        mpSetupPrinter->getPageMargins(&left, &top, &right, &bottom, QPrinter::Millimeter);

        bool bOk;
        newTop = uiPageSetup->marginTop->text().toDouble(&bOk);
        if (!bOk || uiPageSetup->marginTop->text().isEmpty())
            newTop = top;
        newLeft = uiPageSetup->marginLeft->text().toDouble(&bOk);
        if (!bOk || uiPageSetup->marginLeft->text().isEmpty())
            newLeft = left;
        newRight = uiPageSetup->marginRight->text().toDouble(&bOk);
        if (!bOk || uiPageSetup->marginRight->text().isEmpty())
            newRight = right;
        newBottom = uiPageSetup->marginBottom->text().toDouble(&bOk);
        if (!bOk || uiPageSetup->marginBottom->text().isEmpty())
            newBottom = bottom;
        mpSetupPrinter->setFullPage(true); // Disable margin limitation checks
        mpSetupPrinter->setPageMargins(newLeft, newTop, newRight, newBottom, QPrinter::Millimeter);
    }
}
```